# jquery undefined / null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a c programmer and trying to call jquery function from html.

For example from open source I am having below, I would like to make a variable **`wd`** accessible to **webdriver-app.js**

**A.html:**

```
<html>
    <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI + theme (required) -->
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- keyboard widget css & script (required) -->
    <link href="keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.keyboard.js"></script>

    <script src="webdriver.js"></script>
    <script src="base64-arraybuffer.js"></script>
    <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webdriver-app.js"></script>
</head>
<input name="webDriverUrlPort" type="text" onchange="wd.onWebDriverUrlPortChange()" onkeyup="wd.onWebDriverUrlPortChange()"/>
<input name="webDriverUrlPort" type="text" onchange="wd.onWebPageChange()" onkeyup="wd.onWebPageChange()"/>
```

**webdriver-app.js** contains:

```
....
WebDriverJsController.prototype.onWebPageChange = function() {
  this.view.updateSessionDepControls();
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  window.wd = new WebDriverJsController();
});
....
```

Currently, changing above `wd.onWebPageChange()` to `window.wd.onWebPageChange()` gives me `undefined or null` error. What could be wrong in above simplified code?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? Sometimes it provides some context about where the attempt to access `undefined` or `null` occurred.

Comment: include B.js at top

Comment: @gyre Unable to get value of the property 'onWebDriverUrlPortChange"': object is null or undefined

Comment: Can yousee wd defined if you console.log(window); after your window.wd assignment?